# Error: Alarm (Unable to start receiver)

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

Please advice what the problem is with my code...
I am constantly getting this exception any suggestion would be really appreciated.

```
STACK_TRACE=java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.platinumapps.platinumtasks.AlarmReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1975)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:122)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1074)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.platinumapps.platinumtasks.AlarmReceiver.onReceive(AlarmReceiver.java:109)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1968)
... 10 more
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.platinumapps.platinumtasks.AlarmReceiver.onReceive(AlarmReceiver.java:109)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1968)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:122)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1074)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You are getting Null pointer exception ... Check the code 
STACK_TRACE=java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.platinumapps.platinumtasks.AlarmReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Post the code from your `AlarmReceiver.onReceive()`

Answer (score 0):

Its a nullpointer exception.
Means that something you are calling isn't initiated correctly, Or that you dont have access to that part(ei. havn't decalred activities in AndroidManifest. Or havn't included the rights jars etc.)
If you want better help, post the code you are working with.